# Change data type in google sheets using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently I'm getting data from mysql data base for a google sheet by using apps script. When sending the name of the day (ex;-Monday), the sheet automatically takes the data type as string. So I cannot use that variable in google data studio. Other than changing the data type manually in the sheet, how can I change the data type of the sheet using apps script (EX:- String to a variable type like day name using apps script).

Comment: Day name is String what data type you expect for that?

Answer (score 0):

The Range.setNumberFormat function may do what you need.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)

A call to Range.getNumberFormat on an existing cell might help convey how to format your custom format.